# Using jQuery with meteor giving errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Omitting the `keydown input : function(event) {` and `}` gives me an error along the lines of 
"`While building the application:
client/client.js:33:11: Unexpected token (`"
 which is basically the starting. I'm wondering why I need the javascript function right at the start. To not get the error. This is an issue especially because I don't want the click function to run every time the key is pressed. In any case it would be great to either figure out how I can just use jQuery instead of javascript here or change the keydown input.

```
Template.create_poll.events = {

  'keydown input' : function(event) {

    $("input").keypress(function() {
      var active_element = $(this).parent().attr("id");
      var last_child = $('ul li:last').attr("id");
      var option_number_index = last_child.lastIndexOf("-");
      var option_number = last_child.substring(option_number_index+1);
      option_number = option_number/1;

        //console.log(option_number);

        //console.log(last_child);
      if (last_child == active_element) {
        console.log(active_element);
        option_number += 1;
        console.log(option_number);
        $('ul').append('<li id="poll-choice-' +  option_number + '"><input name="choice" type="text" placeholder="Option ' + option_number + '">');
      }
    }); 


    $("#poll_create").click(function() {
      console.log("Button works");
      var choices = new Array();
      var counter = 0;
      $("ul li input").each(function() {
        choices[counter] = $(this).val();
        counter++;
      });

      console.log(choices[1]);
      console.log(choices[5]);

    });

  }



}
```

Comment: You're trying to mix jQuery event code and Meteor event code. When using Meteor as intended, you should find yourself using very little jQuery code, because Meteor is handling the low-level jQuery behind the scenes. You should just implement your events as `"keyup input"` and `"click #poll_create"`

Comment: Can I still use jQuery syntax like `$(this).parent().attr("id");` ?

Comment: The meteor equivalent would be `event.currentTarget.parentNode.id`. Note that this is using default DOM code. I think the new Meteor templating engine that is about to be released uses jQuery, so it might change to be more like what you're doing. I highly recommend reading the [Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/) *from top to bottom*. It explains a lot of these things. You should find yourself barely needing any jQuery syntax at all once you understand how Meteor works. Meteor does the jQuery stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Template.create_poll.events`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events) expects an [`eventMap`](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) which is:

> An event map is an object where the properties specify a set of events to handle, and the values are the handlers for those events. The property can be in one of several forms:

Hence, you need to pass in the `'keydown input' : function (event, templ) { ... }` to make it a valid Javascript object.

In this case, you should follow @Cuberto's advice and implement the events using Meteor's event map:

```
Template.create_poll.events = {

  'press input' : function(event) { 
      var active_element = $(this).parent().attr("id");
      var last_child = $('ul li:last').attr("id");
      var option_number_index = last_child.lastIndexOf("-");
      var option_number = last_child.substring(option_number_index+1);
      option_number = option_number/1;

        //console.log(option_number);

        //console.log(last_child);
      if (last_child == active_element) {
        console.log(active_element);
        option_number += 1;
        console.log(option_number);
        $('ul').append('<li id="poll-choice-' +  option_number + '"><input name="choice" type="text" placeholder="Option ' + option_number + '">');
      }
  },
  'click #poll_create' : function (event) {
      console.log("Button works");
      var choices = new Array();
      var counter = 0;
      $("ul li input").each(function() {
        choices[counter] = $(this).val();
        counter++;
      });

      console.log(choices[1]);
      console.log(choices[5]);

    }
}
```

However, if you want to use certain jQuery specific events, then you can attach them in the `rendered` function:

```
Template.create_poll.rendered = function () {
     $("input").keypress(function() {
      var active_element = $(this).parent().attr("id");
      var last_child = $('ul li:last').attr("id");
      var option_number_index = last_child.lastIndexOf("-");
      var option_number = last_child.substring(option_number_index+1);
      option_number = option_number/1;

        //console.log(option_number);

        //console.log(last_child);
      if (last_child == active_element) {
        console.log(active_element);
        option_number += 1;
        console.log(option_number);
        $('ul').append('<li id="poll-choice-' +  option_number + '"><input name="choice" type="text" placeholder="Option ' + option_number + '">');
      }
    }); 


    $("#poll_create").click(function() {
      console.log("Button works");
      var choices = new Array();
      var counter = 0;
      $("ul li input").each(function() {
        choices[counter] = $(this).val();
        counter++;
      });

      console.log(choices[1]);
      console.log(choices[5]);

    });
};
```

Comment: With this approach it means I cannot use any jQuery syntax including stuff like `$(this).val()`, how can I go about fixing that? 

On aanother note, what's the difference between `rendered` and `event` speed wise and generally the more accepted way to handle events like this.

Comment: Meteor event handler functions get two arguments: `event` and `template`. The `template` argument is a [template instance](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst) object, which as a `find(selector)` method that works similarly to `$(selector)` but is scoped to the template itself and returns a regular DOM `HTMLElement` object. So you can do `template.find("input").value`